# Conditional expectation function and causal inference

Tags: econometrics, causality, conditional-expectation, conditional-independence

**!For the question itself skip to the last paragraph!**

It is my understanding that iff we have a model of the form $$Y = m(X) + e$$ and $E[e|X] = 0$ we know that $m(X)$ is the conditional expectation function thus: $m(X) = E[Y|X]$. If we observe $X$ and $Y$, their relationship is linear in the parameters and we know what this relationship looks like, we can estimate the CEF using OLS. And our estimand will be consistent and unbiased for the true CEF. If either of the assumptions is violated, we only estimate a linear projection model (that can or can not be close to the true CEF).

In texts on causal inference (e.g. Angrist and Pischke 2009), we define the average causal effect as $$E[Y|X, T = 1] - E[Y|X, T = 0] = E[Y(1) - Y(0)|X]$$ ($T$ denotes randomly assigned treatment). If $T$ is binary, I can see that we can fully saturate (include all possible interactions and polynomials, i.e. ensure we capture the correct functional form) the model (assuming $X$ only holds binary variables or is only a constant), which implies that any structural model of the form $$Y = \gamma T + X'\beta + e$$ is in fact the true CEF, and we can estimate our causal effect well (assuming large enough sample, finiteness of moments, and no perfect collinearity).

BUT what if $T$ is continuous? Or random assignment only holds conditional on $X$ and $X$ has continuous components? In that case, how can we know that we are actually estimating the true CEF?  If we aren't, the definition of the causal effect above still holds in the population model, but we can't estimate it using OLS. So why do we still end up using it in cases like this in applied research (I am speaking for econometrics, I don't know how other fields deal with this)?

Comment: from your description, why would it follow that we can't estimate the average treatment effect when $T$ or any of the $X$ are continuous?

Comment: With continuous variables we can't saturate the model so we won't know what the true CEF looks like and/or if we have indeed found an unbiased estimator for it. AND the definition of the ACE is given in conditonal expectations

Comment: hm, I'm not familiar with this concept so I'm not sure I see the problem. Wouldn't a linear regression fitting $Y = \beta X$ to obtain $E(Y|X)$ have the same problem with continuous $X$ and $Y$ according to this reasoning? And yet the OLS estimator is known to be unbiased.

Comment: What do you mean by "saturating the model"?

Comment: @Scriddie Correct me if I am wrong, but OLS will be biased if $E[Y|X]$ is not a function that can be written as linear in its parameters (or if it can be but we don't fit the right model, e.g. the true CEF is $Y=\beta X^2 + e$ but we fit $Y=\gamma X + u$).

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @ArOk I agree with what you're saying here, but I don't see how that's related to the discrete or continuous nature of the random variable.

Comment: @Scriddie if it is binary there is only one form the CEF can take on and that is linear. If it is continuous, there are infinitely many forms the CEF could take on (even if it is linear), so we can't know if we are fitting the right one.

Answer (score 0):

## Linearity is a property of the function, not of the RVs

Given the comments I think I'm beginning to see what the confusion is, so I'll attempt an answer.

The assumption of linearity does not rest upon the variable of intervention (treatment), the covariates, or the target variable being binary random variables. Quite simply, linearity is a property of the function, not of the variables. This is the case for standard linear regression just as much as for estimating a treatment effect.

You are right to note that we may mis-estimate a linear slope parameter from finite data, even if the estimator is unbiased in the sample limit. This is why the rate of convergence to the true parameter and the [efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics)#:%7E:text=An%20efficient%20estimator%20is%20characterized,in%20the%20L2%20norm%20sense.) of the estimator are of interest in many statistical applications.

**Why do we use OLS?**

Well, trying to estimate a non-deterministic function from finite data is comes with the possibility of error. The best one can do is find a good estimator. Under the appropriate assumption OLS is the best linear unbiased estimator. So this, and the fact that it's a rather simple and interpretable estimator, makes it a popular choice.
(Regarding your point about binary variables - even in this case we still could not be sure to arrive at the true relationship given finite data as long as there is randomness.)